# Showing 12 months in 4 rows using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can't for the life of me figure out how to show 12 months over 4 rows with this calendar. I've tried a bunch of different combos for the `numberOfMonths` and nothing. Using jQuery 1.12.1. here's my code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [1,4]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace [1,4] with [4,3]

kindly refer to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Laq2w1bd/)

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
              numberOfMonths: [4,3]
            });
```